# How to list, delete k8 satefulsets in node js?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

how to list statefulsets in node js?

I am using @kubernetes/client-node and is it possible to apply a yaml via node app?

**node app:**

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node');

const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromDefault();

const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api);

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send('Hello World!')
})

app.get('/pods', function(request, response) {
  k8sApi.listNamespacedPod('default').then(
    (result) => {
      response.send(result.body.items)
    }
  )
})

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'))
})
```

referrences: 
https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/statefulset

Comment: do you have any exiisitng code for your node js app?

Comment: thread updated..

Comment: https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client/blob/master/docs/1.10/Pod.md

Answer (score 1):

## List:

[listStatefulSetForAllNamespaces](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/src/gen/api/appsV1beta1Api.ts#L1513)

## Delete:

[deleteNamespacedStatefulSet](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/src/gen/api/appsV1beta1Api.ts#L889)

Note:
should use AppsV1Api instead of CoreV1Api.

```
const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.AppsV1Api)
```

Comment: is it possible to apply a yaml via node?

Comment: k8sApi.listStatefulSetForAllNamespaces is not a function. I am getting this error.

Comment: TypeError: k8sApi.listStatefulSetForAllNamespaces is not a function
        at /home/imran/Desktop/node-js-sample/index.js:18:10
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request]

Comment: code:  app.get('/pods', function(request, response) {
  k8sApi.listStatefulSetForAllNamespaces().then(
    (result) => {
      response.send(result.body);
    }
  )
})